# Delete and sort elements in a object

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, class, object, iteration

I am new to programming and am writing a python program where I have created a class where the objects (stack) are arrays of intigers. I want to be able to delete zero elements in the array, sort the array and want the object to be stored as the "new" sorted array without zero elements. Ex, If I have: stack1=Stack([1, 0, 7, 2]), I want print(stack1.stack) to print [1, 2, 7]. I have tried to use the iter and next method without any success. Any push in the the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
class stack:
   def __init__(self, stack):
      self.stack = stack

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    for elem in self:
        if elem==0:
            self.remove(elem)
    self.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: this looks weird. your class does not extend list - so object is the base class. You store something in self.stack but never use it. you call `self.remove` and `self.sort` but the code does not show those methods. Are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: `self.stack = [s for s in stack if s]` would remove any 0 if `stack = [1,0,1,2,3]`

Comment: to get the output you want you would need to overload `def __str__(self): return str(sorted( (e for e 
 in self.stack if e) ))` - `print(stack1)` would then create a list without Falsys (0 is falsy) and return its strin representation that then gets printed